# Rudin Chap 11, Exc 4: proof check

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, solution-verification

**The exercise:** If $f$ is integrable on $E$ and $g$ is bounded and measurable on $E$, then $fg$ is integrable on $E$ also.

**My proof:** Suppose $f \geq 0, 0 \leq g \leq M$. Note that $fg$ is measurable since $f,g$ are both measurable. Because $fg \geq 0$, there exists a monotonically increasing sequence of simple functions $\{s_n\}$ that converges pointwise to $fg$ on $E$. Hence $|s_n(x)| \leq M \cdot f(x)$ for all $x \in E$. By the Dominated Convergence Theorem, $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_E s_n = \int_E fg.$$

Since $\{s_n\}$ is monotonically increasing, it suffices to show that $\sup \int_E s_n < \infty$. Because $s_n$ is in the set of all simple functions $s$ such that $0 \leq s \leq M\cdot f$, we have that $$\int_E s_n \leq M\int_E f < \infty.$$

From this follows that $M\int_E f$ is an upper bound for $\{\int_E s_n \}$, so $\int_E fg \leq M \int_E f < \infty$. (The other cases follow by similar logic by just dividing $f,g$ into their constituent constant-sign components.)

**I checked some other solution manuals, but none of them seemed to use a simple function approximation for $fg$. They all use simple functions to approximate $g$, so I was wondering if there was anything incorrect with my proof? I'd be grateful if someone could point out any errors. Thank you!**

Comment: Why don't just apply directly the definition of "integrable function" (11.22) and theorem 11.27?

Comment: This is what I did the first time around, but I was just wondering about this solution.

Comment: Calling out the simple functions to prove this exercise is just like you are trying to reprove theorem 11.27. If you want to do that, it is okay. If not, I don't see your point to not use 11.27 instead of your argument.

Comment: So I take it that the proof is alright?

Comment: Well. Not wrong, but just generally acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it might be easier to use Hoelder's inequality. Let $(E,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a measure space, then
$$\bigg|\int_E fg d\mu\bigg|\leq \int_E|fg|d\mu \leq  \|g\|_{\infty}\|f\|_1$$
because $g$ is measurable and bounded and $f \in \mathcal{L}(\mu)$.

---

As for using simple functions. Since $fg$ is measurable, then we can use a simple function approximation:
$$(fg)(x)=\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{j=1}^{N_n}\phi_{j,n}\mathbb{I}_{A_{j,n}}(x)=\lim_{n \to \infty} s_n$$
such that $|s_n|\leq |fg|\leq M|f|$ therefore
$$\int fg d\mu =\int \lim_{n \to \infty} s_n d\mu$$
since $|s_n|\leq M|f| \in \mathcal{L}(\mu)$ we use DC, obtaining that $fg \in \mathcal{L}(\mu)$. All seems ok.

Comment: Thank you for your response!